# Trigger a Windows Runtime background task from Windows 10 Desktop

Tags: windows-runtime, ipc, desktop

I have a Windows 10 Desktop application that needs to use a Windows Runtime API.

Solutions I tried:

1. Enabling Windows Runtime libraries from within my Windows Desktop application – the API was available but failed;
2. using the API in a Windows Runtime background task. There I have not found a reliable trigger so far. The best would be to trigger the background task from my Windows Desktop application.
3. start the Windows Runtime App from Desktop application using the IApplicationActivationManager – works fine, but the suddenly popup of an screen that disappears after few seconds will annoy the customer;

For solution 2., Is there a way to trigger a Windows Runtime background task from my Desktop app?

Comment: What was the failure in #1?

Comment: And, what API are you trying to use?

Comment: The API used is UssdSession.SendMessageAndGetReplyAsync. It does not matter if I use the networkAccId (got with Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.MobileBroadbandAccount.AvailableNetworkAccountIds) or the deviceId. SendMessageAndGetReplyAsync returns after 1 to 3 seconds  UssdResultCode.Terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by using AppServices, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows.applicationmodel.appservice.aspx